# Liquid Dissolve Effect from Akira

Tags: animation, modifiers, animation-nodes, procedural

I am trying to recreate the effect in the below GIF, where blobs rise up off a surface. I've tried multiple approaches, but can't seem to find a solution. My main hope for the solution is that it be highly procedural, i.e could be applied to any kind of mesh object, and the number and density of blobs could be procedurally controlled.

[image]

1st Approach: Metaballs

[image]

The way Metaballs blend together is promising, and I think they would work well if their max influence could be 10x larger. Fiddling with all the settings didn't give me anything nearly long enough.

2nd Approach: Cast Modifier

[image]
The cast modifier offers a nice, procedural way of deforming a mesh to something spherical, but implementing this approach on a large scale seems tedious.

I'm open to solutions that use animation nodes or sverchock.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use `Cycles/Experimental` option
2. Add the `Subdiv Modifier` with `Adaptive` option to your object
3. Have fun with Nodes and displacement (use the `Displacement only` mode in the material option)

Here animating the 3 `value` nodes controlling respectively the color ramp, voronoi blob and noise spike textures.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I appreciate this approach, but I'd really like the blobs and goo bumps to deform in a way where they expand into a more spherical form further away from the mass.

Comment: Free for you to tweak the nodes for your purpose! I thought it would provide a base that you can expand on. My intent was not to create the perfect replica for you.

Comment: I'm just saying that I don't think displacement could get the kind of geometry the effect requires

Comment: Try adding Shrink-wrap modifier to your surface pointing at a plane above. Then add a Smooth modifier followed by a Subsurf turned up high. As the plane approaches the surface will be attracted away.